# Is this Key Value Compliant?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

If I @synthesize my property (artist) everything works fine

1. add observer for keyPath artist.name
2. call [myObj setValue:newArtist forKey:@"artist"];
3. Success.

if I override the setter method with this:

```
- (void)setArtist:(GVArtist *)artist
{
   GVArtist *oldArtist = _artist;

   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"artist"];
   _artist = [artist retain];
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"artist"];

   [oldArtist release];
}
```

and do it again, I get:

Cannot update for observer  for the key path "artist.name" from , most likely because the value for the key "artist" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the MyObject class.

It looks fine to me though....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` stuff; that's all handled automatically so long as your setter's name is KVO-compliant (which `-setArtist:` is.) When you register an observer on `myObj`, Cocoa dynamically makes a subclass of your object and adds the `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` calls automatically. So there's no need for your setter to do those manually, and it might be causing your problems.

Comment: ARG! Brain fart. You are totally right. I would only need to implement that for an array, right? willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey: